# Where to upload DotNet Nuke website images?

Tags: dotnetnuke

I am new to Dot Net Nuke.

I am responsible for maintaining a section of Dot Net Nuke Website. I dont have access to Website root, FTP and Web Site Management functions. I want to add different images in my webpage which are either logos, icons, Section Titles/Headings. How can I manage such images in Dot Net Nuke website?

Thanks,

Answer (score 2):

If permissions have been setup properly, you should be able to upload images, video, and documents through the editor. A Site Admin will need to ensure they grant appropriate permissions (using the permissions functionality at the bottom of the File Manager). The permissions can be very precise to ensure you only have the most basic permissions needed.

If they won't grant you the needed permissions, then its not practical for you to maintain that section of the site.

Answer (score 0):

In the admin interface is a file manager which you can use to manage all the static resources for your DNN Portal. To quickly switch the look and feel of parts of the website you should apply a skin to either a container on a page or the page itself. You can add skins through the admin interface and set them in the appearance section when editing a page.

Comment: That's actually the problem! I don't have access to Admin Interface. All what I have is two tabs: "Common Tasks" & "Current Page". I can play with layout structure, can add module (HTML or Links). I can add contents to HTML & Links Web Parts and can place them in different webpage zones. that's all...